# I recently started working with Jetpack Compose. I've got the following composable:

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

`

```
  @Composable
fun SearchScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { SearchBar() },
        content = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
                Text(stringResource(id = R.string.genreFilter))
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                ) {
                    // some nested Composables
                }

            }},
    )
}
```

But with this code as-is, the whole code within content = {...} is being underlined in red saying Jetpack Compose: Content padding parameter it is not used.  I do not understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lint error warning you about not using PaddingValues coming from content.

```
@Composable
fun Scaffold(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    snackbarHost: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButtonPosition: FabPosition = FabPosition.End,
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(containerColor),
    contentWindowInsets: WindowInsets = ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets,
    content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
)
```

You can either add it as Modifier.padding(it) to your Column or hover red underlined code and click red light bulb and select suppress

[image]